# Outlook Public Calendar

Tags: exchange, outlook, calendar

I have a pretty big problem. My son just moved back to work for me in my firm. We set his computer up and installed Outlook03 connected to an Exchange 2000 server. All emails work, (internal/external) but I cannot for the life of me get his outlook to see the public shared calendar. Please let me know if you need any more info. OS is XP SP3, Office03 is SP3. Only other software that's installed are QuickBooks03-09 and Lacerte00-08.

Edit: The calendar is in the public folder

Comment: Is the public calendar a public folder or is it in a shared mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure your sons account has permissions to see the public shared calendar.  Compare with a known user that can see the permissions.

Comment: Could you link me to how to see permissions?  I was looking around and googling, but I am not very computer savvy.  (I didn't put the Exchange server in or set it up)

Comment: This would be a good start: http://searchexchange.techtarget.com/news/article/0,289142,sid43_gci1025495,00.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a user with administrative or owner rights on the public folder log in to Outlook, and right-click on the public folder in question.  Choose properties, and select the tab called 'Security' (might be called 'Permissions' in O2K3, can't remember).  This tab will have a list of user/groups and their permissions, and you can add or edit the account and its permissions as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the folder tree where the Public Calendar resides.
If the Public calendar is buried under a sub folder (or more) ensure you also add the relevant permissions to your son's account.
The best/easiest route to control this now and in the futre:-
Setup a security group in ADUC, add all the users who need access to the Public Calendar (and other public items in PF). 
Next, in Public Folders, set the access permissions for the security group instead of the individual users... this allows single point of control over who has/or not access to to PF from ADUC. 
If you're in a native mode server environment, you can even have fun with adding security groups to securtiy groups (less and less typing for us poor and tired system admin people...)